# X509Certificate get private key expiration date

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509certficiate2

I didn't find the way how to get the private key expiration date from X509Certificate2. Is it possible with .NET or maybe I should use some third party libs to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

There is property `NotAfter` for this, check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.notafter?view=net-5.0

Comment: This is correct one. Private keys often expire along with public key embedded in certificate.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this property returns expiration date for public key, but in my case the private key has another date expiration than expiration date of public key